# tmap crashes R on loading

Tags: r, installation, tmap

I used tmap and it was working fine until two days ago. I opened a project where tmap was used and worked perfectly, and tmap crashed R on loading (library(tmap)). I use windows 11 and R studio. I tried R versions 4.1.3 and 4.2.0patched, without RStudio on both Intel and AMD-based computers, and the latest tmap from CRAN and also developer one from the Github. However, I could not install older tmap versions from source as I got an error (ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tmap').

I wonder what can be a problem.

Thanks,

Miloš

Answer (score 0):

Deleting rcpp and reinstalling it solved the problem.
Miloš